# Looking for a layout that makes the Container occupy the max space available in a Form

Tags: layout, codenameone

Trying to reproduce this layout:

[image]

I figured I'd use a Box Y Layout for the Form, and then:
- Label "learn English with my app" on top
- Label "Open the dictionary at the bottom"

But I am struggling to have a layout that makes the 4 cells in the middle expand to take the rest of the space in the middle.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want something like this

```
BorderLayout
    North: Learn English with My App
    CENTER:  GridLayout(2,2)
    SOUTH: Open the dictionary
```